# Internet Connection With 7 Public IPs and One Modem

Tags: networking, internet

The school where I work was offered a dedicated internet connection with seven (7) public IPs but just one modem/router.

What I know is that I just need to use a single IP for the school's router and the router with DHCP enabled can now distribute the use of the Internet via access points for wireless and internet cable for wired.

I'm wondering how to make use or take advantage or the rest of the public IP.  I have talked with the ISP's installers and they mentioned that each IP has the same bandwidth.  That's why I now thought that there might be a way to make use of this.

BTW, the purpose for this offer was to let teachers use the internet for distance learning.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: To be clear, by each ip has the same bandwidth, do they mean that all the IPs draw from a single common pool of bandwidth (the most common setup, and meaning that multiple IPs does not increase the total amount available), or that each IP has a separate independent bandwidth allocation?

Comment: I believe that each IP has a separate independent bandwidth allocation.  Thanks again - good question.  I'll take not of this.

Comment: The bandwidth per IP is part of your ISP plan. A basic plan normally deals with the bandwidth that can be delivered with one IP

Answer (score 0):

That is a common business internet service (certainly where I am). So your one router uses one IP address. You can add extra routers or router on another IP address for other services (Guest Internet if you wish).

Put a small 8-port switch attached to the ISP service and then you can add routers as you wish.

Some commercial routers can do fail-over service if you wish one of these and get someone to set it up for you.

Comment: Hey John,

Thanks for the info.  Yes, I thought about that.  7 routers or those advanced ones that have multiple WAN ports.  

Yet, I'm still looking for other possibilities...I'm reading on static routing tables -- maybe I could use this on one router and manage the 6 or 7 ips in this router and distribute these to the LAN.  So I just have to manage this one router gateway.  I'm not really sure if this is how static routing works, though....

Comment: Most routers (even entry level advanced ones) will only handle two IP external addresses  not 6 or 7.